# How to read case-insensitive string of column name pandas

Tags: python, pandas, case-sensitive

How can I read Excel documents which have the same number of columns and it should have same names of columns, but in some columns could be uppercase "d" and in others lowercase "d"?

I am appending data frames which I have to read first, but I have the problem when some columns have the name "Student_IDs" and others "Student_Ids"

for example:

df1

```
  A              Student_IDs
  some text      text
  text           some text
```

df2

```
  A              Student_Ids
  text1          some text1
  text2          some text2
  text3          some text3
```

this is the code (where dirname is the name of folder from which I am reading Excel documents):

```
for f in glob.glob(dirname + "/*.xlsx"):
    dfMerged = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(dfMerged,ignore_index=True)
```

and I have three columns instead of two.

EDIT: I need the names of columns to be "A" and "Student_IDs".

Comment: maybe just lowercase all the columns?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga-No, it should be Student_IDs in the second column.

Comment: Then keep a list of "canonical" names, do the lowercasing for the merging, then re-convert to canonical form.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Could you please write the answer, because I am not familiar with "canonical" names?

Comment: By canonical I just mean *whatever names you want*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by doing 
`dfMerged.columns = [x.lower() for x in dfMerged.columns]` .

Comment: @lazy_frog- But at the end I need the names of columns to be "A" and "Student_IDs".

Comment: You can create a dictionary to save origin names and each lowercase name. such as `{"a": "A", "student_ids": "Student_IDs"}`. Then replace your columns name by searching this dictionary.

Comment: @lazy_frog- Thank you, I could do that, but it is a little problem if I have more than 20 columns...but thanks.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any pattern of your data column names? You can write some rules for matching the right column names. But it's more complicated. I think @juanpa.arrivillaga 's comment is right, set a list of correct names then convert your original column names.